# How to use Fiddler against an OAuth protected REST API?

Tags: rest, fiddler

We use a fancy library for oauth that hides the oauth complexity. But now I need to play with a couple of discrete api calls in fiddler.

Part of the complexity is that the app that interacts with the API is a web app, running on a web server. So I can't use fiddler to see what is going on...

E.g.

```
  my browser --> web server -- > initial oath auth sequence (redirect to API server, sign in..)
  web server --> remote REST API protected by oauth tokens/permissions...
```

So in this layout, I cannot use fiddler to capture the traffic between the web server and the API...

REST apis behind oauth are pretty common these days. Is there approach to using fiddler to interact with such an api?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to be much more specific about what you need to do. Fiddler is a proxy; it shows you all of the HTTP requests from a client, including those related to OAUTH. You can re-issue such calls using Fiddler's Composer tab or the toolbar.

Comment: @EricLaw Thanks!  I rewrite the OP